# Cosmos query to find unique count

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have the following documents in Cosmos where I want to get distinct count of stockNumber with associated lineItems with `Waiting-Reconciliation` status.

**Data:**

Doc-1:

```
{
    "stockNumber": "123",
    "lineItems": [
        {
            "itemState": "Reconciled"
        },
        {
           "itemState": "Waiting-Reconciliation"
        },
        {
            "itemState": "Waiting-Reconciliation"
        }
    ]
}
```

Doc-2:

```
{
    "stockNumber": "234",
    "lineItems": [
        {
            "itemState": "Waiting-Reconciliation"
        }
    ]
}
```

Doc-3:

```
{
    "stockNumber": "345",
    "lineItems": [
        {
            "itemState": "Reconciled"
        },
        {
            "itemState": "Reconciled"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Desired Output:**
Here `"123"` and `"234"` has itemState with `Waiting-Reconciliation` so both of them are qualified.

```
[
    {
        "stockCount": 2,
        "lineItemCount": 3
    }
]
```

**Queries:**

When I run this,

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.stockNumber) AS stockCount, 
COUNT(c.lineItems) AS lineItemCount 
FROM c JOIN l IN c.lineItems 
WHERE l.itemState = 'Waiting-Reconciliation'
```

then I get this error.

```
{"code":"BadRequest","message":"One of the input values is invalid.\r\nActivityId: 1b7d21f5-2d83-4e9a-834c-26729f5bad1d, Windows/10.0.20348 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.18.0"}
```

Now, If I just remove `DISTINCT` then it returns 3 for both, which I don't want. What am I missing here?

```
SELECT 
count(c.stockNumber) AS stockCount, 
count(c.lineItems) AS lineItemCount 
FROM c JOIN l IN c.lineItems 
WHERE l.itemState = 'Waiting-Reconciliation'
```

**Note:**
This runs successfully, but when I try to get the count, it throws the above-mentioned error.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT c.stockNumber AS stockCount,
  c.lineItems AS lineItemCount
FROM c JOIN l 
IN c.lineItems 
WHERE l.itemState = 'Waiting-Reconciliation'
```

Basically, I want to combine these two queries in one. Or at least, combine their results.

```
SELECT COUNT(c) AS stockCount 
FROM c WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(c.lineItems) > 0 
AND EXISTS (SELECT VALUE l FROM l IN c.lineItems WHERE STRINGEQUALS(l.itemState, 'Waiting-Reconciliation', true))
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "stockCount": 2
    }
]
```

```
SELECT
  COUNT(c) AS lineItemCount
FROM c
  JOIN l IN c.lineItems 
WHERE l.itemState = 'Waiting-Reconciliation'
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "lineItemCount": 3
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying with the above query given in the question results both the count as `3` because in the query it is calculating the count of `stockNumber` and `lineItems` individually.

As many trails done using cosmos queries and found one method to get the expected result, you can find unique count in Cosmos using **UDF** and call that when querying.

**UDF for calculating `stockCount`**:
In this function, it checks whether the `doc` contains `lineItems` or not, if it contains then checks if the `itemState` property of the current `lineItem` object is equal to `"Waiting-Reconciliation"` if it is found then it returns 1.

```js
function stockCountUDF(doc) {
    if (!doc || !doc.lineItems) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < doc.lineItems.length; i++) {
        if (doc.lineItems[i].itemState === "Waiting-Reconciliation") {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**UDF for calculating `lineItemCount`**:
In this function, it checks whether the `lineItems` were there or not, if it is there then it checks if the `itemState` property of the current `lineItem` object is equal to `"Waiting-Reconciliation"` if it is found then it returns the `count`.

```js
function lineItemCountUDF(lineItems) {
    if (!lineItems) {
        return 0;
    }
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < lineItems.length; i++) {
        if (lineItems[i].itemState === "Waiting-Reconciliation") {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

**Query I tried with**:
In the below query it summarizes all the `count` returned by the `udf` and prints in the output as shown below.

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(udf.stockCountUDF(c)) AS stockCount,
    SUM(udf.lineItemCountUDF(c.lineItems)) AS lineItemCount
FROM c
```

**Output:**

```js
[
    {
        "stockCount": 2,
        "lineItemCount": 3
    }
]
```